# Writing a function in haskell using recursion to determine how many digits there are in a list of characters

Tags: haskell

I need to count how many digits there are in a list of characters using recursion so for this list `['a','b','c','1','2','3']`  the answer should be `3`

I have managed to do it using this code but I am struggling to do it using recursion

```
counta :: [Char] -> Int 
counta = length . filter isDigit
```

Example:

```
Main> counta ['a','b','c','1','2','3']
```

Answer should be: `3`

Answer (score 3):

Like any recursive function over a list, start by handling the head and recursing on the tail.

```
counta :: [Char] -> Int
counta [] = _
counta (x:xs) = let this = _  -- something involving x
                    that = counta xs
                in _ -- something involving this and that
```

If you try to compile this, the compiler will tell exactly what type each `_` should be, which should help you replace them with the correct expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way - try to understand it before just using it.

```
counta :: [Char] -> Int
counta [] = 0
counta (c:cs)
 | isDigit c = 1 + counta cs
 | otherwise = counta cs
```

Comment: Hi @crjake, welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for answering. It's the tradition of the haskell tag here not to "do people's homework for them". You have the right idea with the request "try to understand it"; but we usually take it one step further by giving a hint, some guidance, explaining what's wrong, or showing a solution to a closely related problem and invite the OP to make the analogy. If you must give a complete solution (occasionally it is called for), try to offer some words of insight along with it: by what principle did you find it; what pattern does it follow; etc. Thanks again!